# how to send and receive data chunk by chunk in linux sockets

Tags: c, sockets

how should it be?

I'm trying to communicate between server and client, server can send big data to client and it needs to do it at once without getting blocked. this data may be 10mb-100mb so I wanted to send it piece by piece but I couldn't do it

Comment: To send/receive messages longer than one byte, you need a protocol on top of TCP.  You also MUST correctly and completely handle results returned from system calls like recv().

Comment: Are you using an UDP or a TCP socket? Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: i use TCP/IP socket

Comment: there's probably other errors - but I would think in `receive_data()`, it should be `i += n`

Comment: @fbyniteyou are right but still not working

Comment: You can send() the whole stuff in one call. send returns then number of bytes sent or -1 if error. If less than requested number of bytes have been sent, only then you loop to send the next chunk.

Comment: Your receive_data function should take one more argument: the size of the buffer. This size will be passed to recv to receive data. If the buffer is to small, the next call to recv will receive more data.

Comment: Using both SIZE and size is really a bad naming convention. You should avoid it.

Comment: Please note that TCP is not datagram oriented. This means that the receiver has no way to know how many bytes the sender sent (unless the length is in the data itself or course). There is **NO** relation between the number of calls to send and the number of calls to recv.

Comment: Doesn't the send function have a limit? also the receiver needs to save this data. How to do that if 100mb data is sent?

Comment: @XLVII The sender should send the data's size before sending the data itself. The receiver can then read the size first and then read until that amount of data has been read.

Comment: There is no problem with send limit. Send will be blocking (unless you set socket in non blocking mode) until there is room for data. TCP is a "window" reliable protocol. Data is sent by packets with CRC and each packet has to be acknowledged by the receiver. But an number of *not yet acknowledged* packets can be sent before the sender stops sending and wait for the acknowledges. Packets are resent in case of missing ACK or NAK (Receiver detected a data corruption).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your 2 functions are a little more complicated than they need to be.  They can be simplified.

For instance, the whole `SIZE` and `LIMIT` handling in `send_data()` can be removed since you are sending the `data` buffer directly, so just give `send()` as many bytes as are in `data` and let `send()` tell you how many bytes it actually accepted.

But more importantly, `receive_data()` needs to take the size of the input `buffer` into account.  You are just blindly reading without any notion of how much data is actually being sent.  You are passing a variable-length string to `send_data()`, which could easily exceed whatever `buffer` size the caller of `receive_data()` is expecting.

Also, you are lacking any error handling at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```c
int send_data(int sockfd, const void *buffer, size_t bufsize)
{
    const char *pbuffer = (const char*) buffer;
    while (bufsize > 0)
    {
        int n = send(sockfd, pbuffer, bufsize, 0);
        if (n < 0) return -1;
        pbuffer += n;
        bufsize -= n;
    }
    return 0;
}

int receive_data(int sockfd, void *buffer, size_t bufsize)
{
    char *pbuffer = (char*) buffer;
    while (bufsize > 0)
    {
        int n = recv(sockfd, pbuffer, bufsize, 0);
        if (n <= 0) return n;
        pbuffer += n;
        bufsize -= n;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Then you can build other functions on top of those. For example, sending a string's length as an integer before sending its characters, eg:

```c
int send_int32(int sockfd, int32_t data)
{
    data = htonl(data);
    return send_data(sockfd, &data, sizeof(data));
}

int receive_int32(int sockfd, int32_t *data)
{
    int ret = receive_data(sockfd, data, sizeof(*data));
    if (ret <= 0) *data = 0;
    else *data = ntohl(*data);
    return ret;
}

int send_str(int sockfd, const char *data)
{
    int32_t size = strlen(data);
    int ret = send_int32(sockfd, size);
    if (ret == 0) ret = send_data(sockfd, data, size);
    return ret;
}

int receive_str(int sockfd, char **data)
{
    *data = NULL;
    int32_t size;
    int ret = receive_int32(sockfd, &size);
    if (ret > 0) {
        *data = malloc(size+1);
        if (*data == NULL) return -1;
        ret = receive_data(sockfd, *data, size);
        if (ret <= 0) {
            free(*data);
            *data = NULL;
        }
        else {
            (*data)[size] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

```c
send_str(sockfd, "Hello World!");
```

```c
char *str;
if (receive_str(sockfd, &str) > 0) {
    ...
    free(str);
}
```